# using curly braces to construct a object not using initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++03

There is a `Container` in my project.

I usually construct the object using curly braces, for example: `Container x{1,2,3}`.

It works well using `std::initializer_list` under C++11.

However, when I move to an environment that does not support C++11, the `std::initializer_list` cannot be used anymore.

Can I still use curly braces to construct a object when am not using initializer_list? Maybe some technique should be used? I am not sure.

Thanks for your time.

## Appendix

The naive implementation is shown as follows (some copy safty is not written here for simplicity):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class Container
{
public:
    explicit Container(std::initializer_list<double> initializer_list)
    {
        size = initializer_list.size();
        data = new double[size];
        int i = 0;
        for (auto it = initializer_list.begin(); it != initializer_list.end(); ++it)
        {
            data[i] = *it;
            i++;
        }
    }

    ~Container()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "--------------" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "[" << i << "]" << data[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    int size;
    double *data;
};

int main()
{
    Container a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    a.print();

    Container b{1, 2, 3};
    b.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [List initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) was added to the language in `c++11`, and is not related to `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Is there any way that I only set the element, then I can construct container?

Comment: boost::assign was the pre c++11 equivalent of initialisers

Comment: "Braced initializer has no type" - Scott Mayers

Comment: @Strongwill Sir, I can not understand. Could you please give some detail explaination or reference link? Thanks.

Comment: https://youtu.be/wQxj20X-tIU?t=1789  There you go, enjoy!